# Change from Google sdk 29 to 30

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

Google has decreed that it needs to change the SDK version to 30 now in August.

I have an App published in the store and I made this change, but 1 week after going up to the store several users reported errors in the app, the app stopped working and closed on certain devices.

Has anyone gone through something similar or do you know if this is something that has been happening?

It was this snippet that I updated in my code:

android/build.gradle

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseVersion = "+"
    }
```

I'm using react native in this application

Comment: Any update? I'm facing the same problem.